# "Not" after a statement that is not a joke

Tags: word-usage, negation

Is it valid to use **Not** after a statement to negate it in joke style when we are not trying to joke but making a point?

Eg., Yes, what you said totally makes sense. Not!

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? Your meaning would be understood, but in terms of grammar, style, and especially etiquette I would suggest you don't do this.

Comment: Do you mean "Or not."?

Comment: @nnnnnn Not in formal discussion, but for discussion on Twitter? I want it to also sound it as a ridicule.

Comment: @Kris no. Just Not! to negate the previous statement.

Comment: You can say what you like, but the issue isn't grammar, it's that this is a lame joke that was funny for a few weeks in the 1990s, but like other out-of-date slang is more likely to make you appear ridiculous than win an argument. Get with the program, daddy-o! https://www.vulture.com/2017/02/mike-myers-talks-waynes-world-not-joke-snl-trump.html

Comment: I'm trying to work out the semantic overlap of 'validity', 'acceptability' and  'grammaticality'. Isn't 'validity' normally reserved for the truth or otherwise of a statement, not the language competence displayed in making it? // 'Not!' is a meaningful fragment (ie 'I was using antiphrasis ... nay, sarcasm ... in the previous statement) and fragments stand outside the demands of normal grammar. Acceptability here is largely a function of the audience involved; this is a matter of sociolinguistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say what you like, but the issue isn't grammar or style, it's that this is a lame joke that was funny for a few weeks in the 1990s, but like other out-of-date slang is more likely to make you appear ridiculous than win an argument. See [Mike Myers on How the “Not!” Joke Went From Wayne’s World to Donald Trump](https://www.vulture.com/2017/02/mike-myers-talks-waynes-world-not-joke-snl-trump.html).

originally written, more or less, as a comment by Stuart F

Another method was to say "Psych!" instead of "Not!" which is equally inane.